# What are the best java/j2ee web application auto code generators?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I know this question is subjective but I would really want to know what are the best j2ee web application auto code generators.

I googled and found out the Appfuse is one of them.

Spring ROO is another but it depends on spring i think.

Are there any other better tools?

Basically lot of time is spent on creating regular CRUD screens with the same mundane things for each screen.

So, I would want to reduce the time spent on such simple CRUD screens so that I can focus more on the core application logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I have seen so far is [Grails](http://www.grails.org/). It generates groovy code, not java but you can interface painlessly with any java library/class. The convention over configuration features are amazing and one can put up a functioning web app in minutes. 
I suggest you see for yourself - just try the [grails screencasts](http://www.grails.org/Grails+Screencasts). They will get you up to speed in 15 minutes.
The technologies used under the hood are best-of-breed : spring, hibernate, lucene, quartz, sitemesh etc.

Answer (score 5):

We use **Telosys** (http://www.telosys.org/) to generate repetitive code like CRUD screens. 
A set of templates are available for Spring MVC, JPA, AngularJS, etc. 
We have customized some of them. It saves of lot of time.